# RxAndroid: даные не попадают в колбек при использовании оператора zip

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava

Использую фреймворк RxAndroid для синхронизации двух API requests, с тем чтобы результаты двух запросов можно было обрабатывать синхронно.

```
Observable
            .zip(fetchAuth(), fetchGmcToken(), new Func2<Auth, String, Credentials>() {
                @Override
                public Credentials call(Auth auth, String token) {
                    logger.info(" startFetchingCredentials: call: auth = "
                            + auth + "; token = " + token);
                    return new Credentials(auth, token);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Credentials>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    logger.info(" Subscriber: onCompleted started ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    logger.info(" Subscriber: onError: exception - " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Credentials credentials) {
                    logger.info(" Subscriber: onNext: credentials = " + credentials.toString());
                }
            });
```

1 запрос, возвращающий Observable

```
    private Observable<Auth> fetchAuth() {
            return ApiClient.get().getGuid(ApiUtils.getBodyForGuid())
            .doOnNext(new Action1<Auth>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Auth auth) {
                    logger.verbose(" fetchGuid: api call: auth - " + auth.toString());
                }
            });
```

2 запрос

```
    private Observable<String> fetchToken() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            String token = null;
            try {
                InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(SplashActivity.this);
                token = instanceID.getToken(SplashActivity.this.getString(R.string.gcm_sender_id),
                        GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
                logger.debug(" fetchToken: api call: token  = " + token);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Вообщем-то все достаточно просто, запросы выполняются и судя по логам значения возвращают. Проблема возникает в колбеке объекта new Func2(), в метод **call** данные не приходят. Подскажите, плз, где затык ибо идеи у меня уже закончились).

**UPD.** Нужно добавить subscriber.onNext(token);, вопрос решился)

Comment: Я ничего не понимаю в Rx, но вам надо как-то вернуть `token` во втором запросе. Вроде это делается через `subscriber.onNext(result); subscriber.onCompleted();`

Comment: да, все верно, действительно, в данном случае надо сделать явно вызов колбека subscriber`а, заработался))